# how to keep reducing several numbers and each stops at a pre determined value

Tags: python, python-2.7

let's say i have several numbers and i want to keep reducing each of them by some given value. each number must stop reducing at a pre determined value. My code is below.

```
a = b = c = 100
x = y = 1
print a, b, x, y
s = 1

while s:
    if a >= 11:
        a -= x
    if b >= 2:
        b -= y
    if c >= 21:
        c -= y

    print a, b, c

    if a == 10 and b == 1 and c == 20:
        s = 0
```

Can this be done in a more efficient way?

Comment: What is your use case? Will `a` and `b` always decrement by the same amount? Generally it is more pythonic and faster to use `for` loops, but will only work is the decrement is constant

Comment: i need to use this to reduce some counters which will stop at predetermined values. I edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use python lists, that way you can define any amount of numbers each with their own decrease and their own stop limit, adding a number is as simple as adding the values to each list rather than having to type extra code;

```
numbers = [10, 100, 1000]
decrease = [1, 10, 100]
stop = [5, 50, 500]

b = True
while b:

  b = False
  for c, n in enumerate(numbers):
    if n <= stop[c]:
       continue
    numbers[c] = n - decrease[c]
    b = True

print numbers # [5, 50, 500]
```

Comment: would this be faster than the method above?

Comment: It would be hard to tell without benchmarking. The difference would be minimal anyway. What is more important is readability and maintainability.

Comment: if we are looking at a large amount of numbers, wouldn't the list method take up more memory?

Comment: Probably yes, but regardless of which method you use each number, limit, and deficit would still require memory. Pre optimisation is not good. Use code that is easier to maintain and read before worrying about speed.